# Tesseract API и русский язык

Tags: c++, unicode, locale, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Распознаю русские буквы белым по черному, распознается вроде как успешно, но при попытке вывести в консоль - фейл. Выводится символ `Ð` на все буквы, а на букву `З` - тройка.

В дебаггере это выглядит как `sym[0] -42:Ð`.

При этом вхардкоженый русский текст выводится адекватно...

В чем дело?

Код:

```
TessBaseAPI tess;
tess.Init(NULL, "rus", OEM_DEFAULT);
tess.SetPageSegMode(PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);

Mat& current = tiles[0];
cv::imshow("dev", current);
cv::waitKey(0);
tess.SetImage(current.data,
              current.size().width,
              current.size().height,
              current.channels(),
              current.channels() * current.size().width);
char* sym = tess.GetUTF8Text();

symbols.push_back(sym[0]);
std::cout << sym[0] << std::endl;
```

UPD: Проверил верность распознавания через консольный *tesseract* - с теми же параметрами все верно распознал, отдал юникондую строку.

Comment: Эээ... А текст utf-8 правильный? Если вывести utf-8-строку в файл, и открыть его как текст utf-8, видно то, что надо?

Comment: Не-а.
```Русская локаль
Ð```

Comment: @VladD сначала просто перенаправил вывод (рукалицо)... Сейчас вывел именно как строку потоком, то же самое -- ```Ð``` и тройка

Comment: @mersinvald , может быть это нужно добавить: `setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "C");`

Comment: @alexis031182 у меня linux, локали и так правильные.

Comment: Да и смысл в "С"? Тем более в нумерике. Тройка вместо З у меня и так вполне хорошо выводится)

Comment: В отличии от кирилицы

Comment: Подождите, а если вывести строку в файл просто как последовательность байт, не через `cout`, то что? Может, у вас у `cout` не та локаль.

Comment: @VlaD а это мысль. Попробую.

Comment: @VlaD если Вы правы - как чинить?

Comment: Посмотрим, что покажет эксперимент. То есть мы сейчас пытаемся выяснить, где проблема: в строке. приходящей с `GetUTF8Text`, или с консольным выводом. Или с системой :)

Comment: @VladD вывел, все то же: одна цифра(53) и байты значением -42.

Comment: @VladD сейчас попробовал прочитать из файла русский текст и вывести его в другой файл - то же самое: все русские символы стали -42.

Comment: Подождите, а давайте проще: какое содержимое строки `sym`? Побайтно. Посмотрите в отладчике.

Comment: Русские символы в utf-8 должны выглядеть так: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024

Comment: @VladD идентично stdout и выводу в файл

Comment: Тогда функция `GetUTF8Text` выдаёт что-то не то :-( Посмотрите точно по таблице utf-8, что же она и правда вам пытается выдать.

Comment: @VladD любые символы введенные через файловые потоки или stdin превращаются в -42:Ð, при этом строка забитая в коде выводится абсолютно нормально. Вывод: что-то со вводом нечисто.

Comment: Пойду на лоре спрошу: если помогут - отпишусь

Comment: @mersinvald: Нееее, посмотрите в отладчике конкретный набор байтов. `-42` не является полным юникодным символом, это лишь первая часть двухбайтного символа. Что следует за ним?

Comment: @VladD у меня начинает взрываться мозг. UTF-8 у меня, как и должен быть, 1 байт. Значение всех кирилическах букв в переводе из HEX - 208(d0 hex), значение тройки, как и должно быть, 53(33 hex) https://habrastorage.org/files/79a/4c1/4a5/79a4c14a590d400f8d6d23ae22f03011.png

Comment: @VladD и так для всей кирилицы, полученной, так сказать, извне

Comment: @mersinvald: Вот и отлично. Вы видите, что к вам приходит невалидный utf-8. Потому что для utf-8 для каждого русского символа после `d0` **должен идти ещё код символа**. `А = d0 90`, `Б = d0 91` и т. д. Юникодные символы занимают переменное количество байт. Числа — по одному байту, русские буквы — по два.

Comment: @VladD вот оно что... Есть предположения с чем это может быть связано? Чего я при настройке мог не учесть, из-за чего так происходит?

Comment: @mersinvald: Нет, идей нету. Возможно, где-то по пути какая-то часть софта считает, что все символы непременно однобайтные, и теряет второй байт? В любом случае, надеюсь, это наведёт вас на правильный путь.

Comment: @mersinvald: Может быть, `tess.Init(NULL, "rus", OEM_DEFAULT);` всё портит?

Comment: @VladD почему он должен? Это просто инициализация тессеракта с нужной развесовкой для русского языка, NULL говорит что все в дефолтной папке лежит, а последний параметр говорит что надо все системы инициализировать.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, буду искать решение.

Comment: @mersinvald: Вы уверены насчёт `OEM_DEFAULT`? Под Windows OEM-кодировки все однобайтные, поэтому меня насторожило слово OEM. Если с ним всё в порядке, то у меня идей не осталось. Удачи вам в поисках!

Comment: Посмотри тут, похожая проблема. Человек пишет что помогли функции Qt, и он перевел из UTF-8 в Unicode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976592/tesseract-does-not-recognize-russian

Comment: @Denis_Zaikin спасибо, но Qt в данном случае - из пушки по воробьям. Проблему решил используя трехбайтные строки для символов и свои реализации string.h